# If text is entered into a particular cell, the cell to the right automatically populates with text

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help!
I'm working on a price guide that includes part numbers. Several of the same part numbers are associated with different products so they appear at various places throughout the price guide. I've found instances where I've forgotten to update some of the cells. I'd like Excel to do this automatically, if possible.
For example, if I enter part number ACH in column B, in any row on the spreadsheet, I'd like Column C to automatically populate with $100.00. 
Is this possible? C10 may be a part simply trying to eliminate data entry error and rely on an Excel formula or code to help me.

I know nothing about VBA codes (which, after researching, I suspect I'll have to write), so please "dumb-down" your answer!

Thank you so much!

Comment: table look up? use `VLOOKUP` ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a macro that will prompt you for the part number to search for and a price to enter.  It will search column B for that part number and replace the adjacent price in column C with the new price.

```
Sub ReplacePrice()
    lastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim searchRng As Range
    Set searchRng = Range("B1:B" & lastRow)


    Dim partNum As String

    partNum = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Part Number to Search For: ", _
          Title:="ENTER PART NUMBER", Default:="Your PN here")

    ' Check for invalid input
    If partNum = "Your PN here" Or partNum = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Dim price As String

    price = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter price: ", _
          Title:="ENTER PRICE", Default:="Your price here")

    ' Check for invalid input
    If price = "Your price here" Or price = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    ' Finds each matching part number in col B and replaces adjacent price in col C
    For Each cell In searchRng
        If cell.Value = partNum Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = price
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

How to use this code:

- Turn on developer tab (File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Check 'Developer' on right hand panel -> Ok
- Now click on your developer tab (to the right of the view tab)
- Now click on VBA which is on the far left of the ribbon
- Right click 'Microsoft Excel Object' in the tree on the left side of the VBA window
- Click 'insert' then 'Module'
- Now double click the new module in the tree which is defaulted to 'Module 1'
- Paste this code into the blank white screen on the right
- Put your cursor somewhere in the text (anywhere between Sub and End Sub) and hit F5 to run.
- Now you can go back to Excel and create a button and link it to your macro (I'll leave this up to you to research :-)

---

You'll be prompted with a few input boxes like this:

[image]

[image]

If your data looks like this:

[image]

And you enter "DEF" for part number and "8" for price you now see this:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you copy your workbook for testing as a macro has no undo!  There is limited error checking provided. A lot of this would be dependent on your data.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out tomorrow at work and let you know the outcome! You've saved me a ton of time and significantly decreased the margin for data entry error! I appreciate your response.